# Windows 10 License

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, license-key

I recently custom built my own desktop computer and had questions regarding getting a windows license. The price for windows 10 home is $130, while pro is $200 (ouch!)

I had an old retired dell laptop with windows 8 home, so I decided to use its license key to activate my freshly installed windows 10, it worked! I have read that windows upgrade from 8 to 10 isn't possible anymore so I have the following questions:

1. How was I still able to upgrade and use the windows 8 license key to activate windows 10 in 2022?
2. Also I have read that OEM licenses (which is what my old laptop would have had) can't be transferred to new hardware, so what's up with that? mine seems to be working, will it just stop suddenly?
3. I am looking into upgrading from windows 10 home to pro, but that costs $100 rather than $70 (which is the difference between home and pro), this doesn't make sense. Anyway articles online indicate that the upgrade of an OEM license again can't be transferred, is that true?
4. Will I also get a free upgrade to windows 11 pro (after purchasing the $100 upgrade)?
5. Since I used the old windows 8 key and logged into my microsoft account, do I now have a digital license for windows 10, where do I find this as a purchased product in my account?
6. Should I just skip the hassle and purchase the $200 windows 10 pro license from microsoft online (that would be $100 more)?

I know its a lot, but I appreciate any help on the matter,

Thanks in advance - Alex

Comment: Windows OEM licenses cannot be transferred. You need to purchase a new license

Comment: For 1 and 2 you may have activation issues at some point because you moved an OEM license. The rest depends on what happens for number 2.

Comment: Microsoft currently only sells Retail Windows 10 licenses online, which can be used to install Windows 11. There is no upgrade offer from Windows 8 or Windows 7 to windows 11. In fact you cannot upgrade directly to Windows 11 if your running either of those versions

Comment: That you have an Windows key for Windows 8 is strange, usually the license should be included in the system BIOS. By definition of Microsoft OEM licenses can not be transferred but as far as I know this is not the legally correct in some countries. You should check that if that also applies to your country. If it is legal an [OEM] license can still be upgraded to Win 10 to my knowledge.

Comment: **ALL** Windows 8+ OEM keys are stored in the ACPI table for the device.  If it's not stored there then the key is a Retail Windows 8+ key.  There are zero Windows 8+ machines with a printed COA sticker with the license key printed on it.  The only Windows 8+ COA stickers that have a license key printed on them came with Windows 8 Retail licenses.

Answer (score 1):

> How was I still able to upgrade and use the windows 8 license key to activate windows 10 in 2022?

Officially, the free upgrade offer to Windows 10, for users running Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, expired back in 2017.  In reality until Windows 10 is unsupported, it's very likely, Windows 10 will continue to accept Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 license keys during the installation process.  **Windows 11 cannot be installed with Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 license keys.**

> I have read that OEM licenses (which is what my old laptop would have had) can't be transferred to new hardware, so what's up with that? mine seems to be working, will it just stop suddenly?

OEM Windows licenses cannot be transferred to new hardware.  Windows can indicate an installation, is activate and only after 180 days, switch to it's actual activation status.  Using an OEM license on non-OEM hardware places you in an unsupported state.

> I am looking into upgrading from windows 10 home to pro, but that
> costs $100 rather than $70 (which is the difference between home and
> pro), this doesn't make sense. Anyway articles online indicate that
> the upgrade of an OEM license again can't be transferred, is that
> true?

The price difference between Windows Home and Windows Processional is around The price of a Windows 10 Professional OEM license is different than the price of a Windows 10 Professional Retail license.  **The quoted prices, you are presenting, is likely comparing Retail to OEM license prices.**

> Will I also get a free upgrade to windows 11 pro (after purchasing the $100 upgrade)?

ALL Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional installations, running on eligible hardware, can be upgraded to Windows 11.  Upgrading to Windows 11 on unsupported hardware is also possible with some additional steps.  There is no direct upgrade path, from Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 to Windows 11, that does not first involve upgrading to Windows 10.

> Since I used the old windows 8 key and logged into my Microsoft account, do I now have a digital license for windows 10, where do I find this as a purchased product in my account?

Windows 10 uses a digital entitlement activation process.  There isn't a website where you can view this product information other then the page that displays the devices linked to your Microsoft Account.  Since you performed an upgrade to Windows 10, you don't actually have a Windows 10 license key, if you were to view the Windows 10 key you are currently using it would be the same generic key that everyone uses.

Comment: I have purposefully NOT answered the question, with regards if you should purchase a license, any answer I provided would be my personal opinion.  Questions seeking the communities opinion are out of scope.  I encourage you to remove that particular question from your question.